# Implementing ads shows this error: Support for pending purchases must be enabled

Tags: android, android-billing

According to the documentation, implementing ads are simply in-apps consumable purchases, **and of course are not censed to be pending purchases!** (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_rewarded_products + https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime + https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview).

However my app crashes at this line:

```
                billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(fragmentActivity)
                        .setChildDirected(BillingClient.ChildDirected.CHILD_DIRECTED)
                        .setUnderAgeOfConsent(BillingClient.UnderAgeOfConsent.UNDER_AGE_OF_CONSENT)
                        .setListener(that).build();
```

The error shown is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Support for pending purchases must be enabled. Enable this by calling 'enablePendingPurchases()' on BillingClientBuilder.

So according to the documentation I read, this is in contradiction. Is it normal to enable pending purchases even for simple ads???

Answer (score 2):

From the error mention by you from stacktrace

> Enable this by calling 'enablePendingPurchases()'

we can find documentation for method `enablePendingPurchases()`

> This method is required to be called to acknowledge your application has been updated to support purchases that are pending. Pending purchases are not automatically enabled since your application will require updates to ensure entitlement is not granted before payment has been secured. For more information on how to handle pending transactions see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview
>
> If this method is not called, BillingClient instance creation fails

**Your line of code should be:-**

```
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(fragmentActivity)
                            .setChildDirected(BillingClient.ChildDirected.CHILD_DIRECTED)
                            .enablePendingPurchases()
                            .setUnderAgeOfConsent(BillingClient.UnderAgeOfConsent.UNDER_AGE_OF_CONSENT)
                            .setListener(that).build();
```

> May be you forgot to add this line `.enablePendingPurchases()`

**Hope it will help**

Comment: My question is : is it normal that I have to put this line? Because I'm just using ads.

Comment: Yes, it is normal

Comment: Sorry but pending purchases don't seem to include ads. I really don't understand why enabling the pending mode is required, can you explain it by quoting some official sources? Documentation gives an example of pending purchases : something that mu be bought to a physical store. Ads are totally different